# I'm getting trouble converting String to int while the String is not all numbers

Tags: java, string, types, integer

I would like to convert some of the `String`s I get from **TextInput** to `int`, only I don't know how to remove the parts that are not numbers. Here's an example:

```
String text = "My number is 0111-473-8922";
```

Is there a way to remove the text and dashes (basically whatever isn't a number) so I could convert it to `int`?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Look up regular expressions (regex) to do this

Comment: In the future, please first search on your problem and *show the results of your efforts in your question*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a simple regex and parse the result:

```
String text = "My number is 0111-473-8922";
try{
     int number = Integer.parseInt(text.replaceAll("[^\\d]", ""));
     System.out.println("number: " + number);
}catch(Exception e){
     System.out.println("error: " + e);
}
```